# IDA Pro string function

Tags: ida

I have this binary file that I wish to edit, however after loading it, all strings are in some sort of gibberish symbols. Is there anyway to format it?

Comment: The strings are likely obfuscated in the executable image and then deobfuscated before their use at runtime.  You can patch over the bytes in IDA by writing a small IDC script to emulate the deobfuscation routine on each of the strings.  Alternatively, you can run the program in a debugger and copy the modified strings out of memory into IDA, e.g., as repeatable comments.  I can elaborate on either of these techniques if you want.

Comment: Would love to know more on the techniques you mention. It will definitely help me in it.

Comment: All right, cool.  I submitted my response as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Why you are seeing "gibberish":

**The strings are likely obfuscated.**  Chances are, before each of the strings is used in the program, a deobfuscation routine is run to convert the string in memory back into something meaningful.  This is a common technique used to prevent static analysis tools (such as the GNU "strings" utility or IDA Pro) from properly analyzing the binary.  The rest of this answer makes the assumption that this is true of your binary.

### How to deobfuscate the strings (dynamic approach):

If you are able to run the binary, you can let it take care of the deobfuscation for you.  All you need to do is run the binary in a debugger and analyze the memory after it has been deobfuscated.

Several binaries that obfuscate their strings never re-obfuscate them after their use, so one interesting shortcut you might want to try first is to run the binary in a debugger and break execution right before it exits.  If the strings are still debofuscated, you can do a memory dump of the appropriate section to save the deobfuscated strings.  (This will not necessarily deobfuscate all of the strings for you; you'll only get the strings that were deobfuscated along the path of the binary's execution)

If the previous method does not work for you, try setting a hardware write breakpoint on the first byte of an obfuscated string, then running the binary.  If the breakpoint trips, step through the instructions to allow the rest of the string to be deobfuscated.  If the deobfuscation always happens from a common routine, you can place a breakpoint near the end of that routine and possibly script your debugger to print the debofuscated string each time execution passes through that routine.

Once you have a list of deobfuscated strings, you can either patch them directly into the IDA database (discussed below), or you can leave repeatable comments (use the `'` key) at the addresses of each of the strings in the database, such that the deobfuscated string will display as a comment on every instruction that references it.

For small binaries, you can get away with doing the annotations by hand, but it would be worthwhile to read into scripting IDA so that you can automate this process.  [The IDA Pro Book](http://www.idabook.com/) contains a great reference for this.

### How to deobfuscate the strings (static approach):

If you can't run the binary, or if the dynamic approach isn't deobfuscating all the strings for you, then you can deobfuscate them yourself.

Chances are good that if you view the cross-references to any of the obfuscated strings in IDA Pro (view them with the `x` key), you should be taken to the deobfuscation routine.  If the routine isn't too complicated -- and they usually aren't -- you should be able to write a script to emulate the debofuscation routine.  This will allow you to replace the obfuscated strings with the deobfuscated strings in the IDA database.

(As a point of clarification, the IDA database is entirely separate from the binary itself.  Anything you do to the database will have no effect on the actual binary, and anything you do to the binary will have no effect on the database)

Your options for scripting IDA are IDC (IDA's original built-in scripting language) and IDAPython.  I highly recommend using IDAPython, as it is much easier to use, and a much more powerful language.  I'm not sure if you can install IDAPython on IDA Free 5.0, but it should be bundled with all vaguely recent versions of IDA Pro.

Giving an overview of scripting IDA would be beyond the scope of this answer, but here's an example to get you started.  I'm writing it in IDC in case you're using IDA Free.  Let's say your deobfuscation routine simply XOR'd each successive byte with 0x1F until the null byte was decoded.  Then the following loop might end up being part of your IDC script:

```
// *EXAMPLE*
auto addr = 0x00401000; // The address of your string

while(1){
    auto b = Byte(addr) ^ 0x1F;
    PatchByte(addr, b);
    if (b == '\0'){
        break;
    }
    addr = addr + 1;
}
```

Running a script can be done from `File > IDC Command...` or `File > Script file...`.

As you might guess, `Byte` returns the byte stored at a given address, and `PatchByte` writes a byte to an address.  Built-in functions in IDAPython share the same names with their IDC counterparts, so the IDAPython version would be nearly identical, sans the C-like syntax.  As mentioned before, I highly recommend [The IDA Pro Book](http://www.idabook.com/) for a walkthrough on scripting IDA.  Once you have the basics down, you can use IDA's built-in help index and [The IDAPython documentation](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/) as a couple other references.

**Always save your database before running a script that patches code!** There is no "undo" feature in IDA, so a small coding error could trash your entire database.

Good luck!